# collecstatic modified files using s3boto and django-storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I checked out the following question: [Django StaticFiles and Amazon S3: How to detect modified files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618013/django-staticfiles-and-amazon-s3-how-to-detect-modified-files) and others but i'm still not able to run `collectstatic` on only modified files.

Besides not picking up on modifications, it syncs properly.

I added: `AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True` and ran `collectstatic` completely with this setting turned on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I was missing `python-dateutil`, which somehow didn't make into `django-storages` as a dependency. Make sure you have version 1.1.5 of `python-dateutil` installed or you will get the following error:

```
iter() returned non-iterator of type ‘_timelex’
```

See also my blogpost about this problem and the django - s3bot setup in general [here](http://c4urself.posterous.com/djangos-collectstatic-with-s3boto).