# Make 'collectstatic' find updated files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Is there a way to make `python manage.py collectstatic` find updated static files? Currently, it is properly searching `STATICFILES_DIRS` and finding where I have my static files,  but it only uploads new ones. If I modify a static file, it does not detect this. Does Django do this so we have to delete each file first, or is there an easy solution?

Comment: It by default looks for new and modified files.

Comment: I don't believe I changed any of the defaults, and I am not using any specific flags when calling collectstatic. It still is finding new files, but is not detecting changes to my CSS files, and most likely my other static files.

Comment: And try to use python manage,py collecstatic -n

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

**Disclaimer - This issue has to do with external hosting on Amazon's S3 Storage**

I had simply forgot to include `AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True` in my `settings.py` file.
Adding this setting in fixed the issue of `collectstatic` only finding new files. Also, I saw a major speed increase in syncing between the server and Amazon's S3.

If you are using S3 for storage, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618013/django-staticfiles-and-amazon-s3-how-to-detect-modified-files?rq=1) to be quite helpful.

Comment: I'm havin the same issue, and while changing that setting did seem to speed things up, it still didn't detect some modified files. Any other ideas on why collectstatic wouldn't find updated files?

Comment: `AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA ` is now [deprecated](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/293).  If you have a S3 bucket with many files this setting would cause a server to attempt to load a list of all those files and slow down, or in my case crash.